# Xamrin Forms Android backup Exclude File

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I would like to exclude my apps SQLite database file in my Android backup. The backup currently
includes all of my *.CSV/*.JPG backups in the below paths which are required but the SQLite database
always seems to get included even when I use an `<exclude>` rule in my backup rules XML file.

Paths:
/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/*.csv (required, all CSV files backed up)
/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/*.jpg (required, all JPG files backed up)
/data/user/0/com.CompanyName.AppName/files/.local/share/myappdb.db (not required, but backed up anyway!)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application> 
...
android:allowBackup="true" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backuprules"
...     
</application>
```

backuprules.xml (does not work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
<exclude domain="database" path="myappdb.db"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

backuprules.xml (does not work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
<exclude domain="database" path="."/>
</full-backup-content>
```

Don't know if I need domain="files" path="???" to exclude the database. I don't want to use
`<include>` for the CSV/JPG files as wildcards are not supported and I require all CSV/JPG
files to be backed up.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: Have you try to use the full path of the database in your backuprules? And If you want to backup all the CSV/JPG files, we suggest to use the include tag. Check the link below. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

Comment: Wendy, Thanks for the reply. I have read all of the Android auto backup documentation but it is not clear. I will try the hard coded path as you suggest but I am not sure this would be consistent across different Android versions. Thanks Paul.